# CSS - Background image not displaying

Tags: java, css

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to get a background image to display. The java code is:

```
absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
absolutePanel.setSize("600px", "600px");
absolutePanel.getElement().setId("cwAbsolutePanel");
absolutePanel.addStyleName("absolutePanel");

final Image img = new Image(Resources.INSTANCE.baseballBall());
absolutePanel.add(img, 10, 10);
```

CSS:

```
.absolutePanel {
  background-image: url(bbdiamond.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The path of the image and CSS file are:

[image: path of image and CSS file]

I have tried `"url('bbdiamond.png');"` and `"url(..\bbdiamond.png);"` and `"url('..\bbdiamond.png');"`.
I have also tried giving `.absolutePanel` a height and width of 100% each; `background-color: white` and `opacity: 1`.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Comment: Hi @Glyn Can show live link

Comment: Hi @Mr_Green, I am afraid I do not know what you mean by "Can show live link". Can you be a little bit more specific in your answer please. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Glyn, wrong ping... :) It was actually asked by @RohitAzad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, however when I started testing this morning the CSS background was displayed. I have not made any changes to the CSS or the AbsolutePanel. In future if I am having issues with CSS I will reboot first.

Regards,

Glyn